# Get not selected word in column

Tags: sql-server

I have this table structure and data and query that is giving me the child records. This is giving me required data as I wanted now there is another requirements that popped up with time that I want to show the name of the COA which is not selected here i.e `Medical`

```
CREATE TABLE TransactionMaster
(
ID Int,
TransactionCode VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

INSERT INTO TransactionMaster VALUES (1, 'TRA-001');
INSERT INTO TransactionMaster VALUES (2, 'TRA-002');
INSERT INTO TransactionMaster VALUES (3, 'TRA-003');

CREATE TABLE TransactionDetail
(
ID Int,
MasterID Int,
COATitle VARCHAR(25),
CrAmount NUMERIC(18,2),
DrAmount NUMERIC(18,2),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (MasterID) REFERENCES TransactionMaster(ID)
)


INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (1, 1, 'Medical', '2500', NULL)
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (2, 1, 'Travelling', NULL, '2500')
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (3, 1, 'Medicine', NULL, '2500')
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (4, 1, 'Doc Fee', NULL, '2500')
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (5, 2, 'Incentive', '3000', NULL)
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (6, 2, 'Extra', NULL, '2500')
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (7, 2, 'Bonus', NULL, '500')
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (8, 3, 'Medical', NULL, '3000')
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (9, 3, 'Tests', '2500', NULL)
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (10, 3, 'Juice', '500', NULL)
```

Sample Query:

```
SELECT
  m.TransactionCode,
  d.COATitle,
  d.CrAmount,
  d.DrAmount
FROM TransactionDetail d
JOIN TransactionMaster m ON d.MasterID=m.ID
WHERE d.MasterID IN(
      SELECT MasterID
      FROM TransactionDetail
      WHERE COATitle='Medical'
    )
  AND d.COATitle<>'Medical'
```

Output giving:

```
TransactionCode           COATitle                  CrAmount                                DrAmount
------------------------- ------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
TRA-001                   Travelling                NULL                                    2500.00
TRA-001                   Medicine                  NULL                                    2500.00
TRA-001                   Doc Fee                   NULL                                    2500.00
TRA-003                   Tests                     2500.00                                 NULL
TRA-003                   Juice                     500.00                                  NULL
```

I want to include another column that'll show `Medical`in it.

Expected Output:

```
TransactionCode           COATitle                  CrAmount                                DrAmount                      COA
------------------------- ------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------------- ------------------------
TRA-001                   Travelling                NULL                                    2500.00                       Medical
TRA-001                   Medicine                  NULL                                    2500.00                       Medical
TRA-001                   Doc Fee                   NULL                                    2500.00                       Medical
TRA-003                   Tests                     2500.00                                 NULL                          Medical
TRA-003                   Juice                     500.00                                  NULL                          Medical
```

Comment: please include the expected result

Comment: @Squirrel Please check now

Comment: where is this `Medical` comes from ? Can you explain the logic behind ?

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @prm nvarchar(100)
SET @prm = 'Medical'  

 SELECT
      m.TransactionCode,
      d.COATitle,
      d.CrAmount,
      d.DrAmount,
      @prm as COA
    FROM TransactionDetail d
    JOIN TransactionMaster m ON d.MasterID=m.ID
    WHERE d.MasterID IN(
          SELECT MasterID
          FROM TransactionDetail
          WHERE COATitle=@prm
        )
      AND d.COATitle<>@prm
```

Comment: This is dynamic query, What if use provides something else as input parameter ?

Comment: You can use parameters on select statement. Edited the answer.